# Prove that $(n+1)\int_0^1{\frac{x^n}{x+1}dx}\to\frac12$

Tags: integration, limits

Let $I_n=\int_0^1{\frac{x^n}{x+1}dx}$ , $n>0$

Show that $\lim_{n->\infty}{(n+1)I_n} = \frac{1}{2}$

All I could do was to show that the $I_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: $$(n+1)I_n=\int_0^1\frac{du}{1+u^{1/(n+1)}}\to\int_0^1\frac{du}{1+1}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may just integrate by parts,
$$
\begin{align}
I_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x+1}dx&=\left. \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)}\frac{1}{(x+1)}\right|_0^1+\frac{1}{(n+1)}\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^2}\:dx\\\\
&=\frac1{2(n+1)}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(n+1)}\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^2}\:dx}
\tag1
\end{align}
$$ then observe that
$$
0\leq \color{blue}{\frac{1}{(n+1)}\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^2}\:dx}\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)}\frac{1}{(0+1)^2}\int_0^1x^{n+1}dx=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\tag2
$$
Then using $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives easily

> $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty}nI_n=\frac12.$$

Comment: Pour les inégalités (2) quel(le) théorème ou propriété vous permet de justifier la deuxième inégalité?

Comment: Le simple fait que $\frac1{(x+1)^2}\leq \frac{1}{(0+1)^2}$ sur l'intervalle $[0,1]$.

Comment: En effet c'est élégant ! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Since
$$
\dfrac{x^n}{1+1}\le \dfrac{x^n}{x+1} \le \dfrac{x^n}{x+x}
$$
we get that
$$
\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)} \le I_{n} \le \dfrac{1}{2n}.
$$
Consequently
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}(n+1)I_{n} = \dfrac{1}{2}.
$$